# single input django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to get a single input from django form but its giving me error 
*ValueError at /books/f/
The view main.views.select_team didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*

view

```
def select_team(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Team.objects.create(user=request.user, total=request.POST('team_number'))
        return redirect(reverse('books', args=()))
```

form

```
 <form action="{% url 'select_team' %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="number" id="start" name="'team_number'" min="2" max="5" value="2"/>
 <label for="start">select in range of 2 to 5</label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; create teams
</button>
</form>
```

url

```
url(r'^books/f/$', views.select_team, name='select_team')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must render your template the time you hit the url to test your form. For that use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

```
return render(request, 'template_name.html')
```

Then to grab POSTed data use `request.POST.get('team_number')`. So your view now is:

```
def select_team(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Team.objects.create(user=request.user, total=request.POST.get('team_number'))
        return redirect(reverse('books', args=()))
    return render(request, 'template_name.html')
```

And you are double quoting the `name="team_number` attribute of the input, so the template should be:

```
<form action="{% url 'select_team' %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" id="start" name="team_number" min="2" max="5" value="2"/>
    <label for="start">select in range of 2 to 5</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; create teams
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view doesn't return anything for non-POST request. You should add return statement to the view like this:

```
def select_team(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Team.objects.create(user=request.user, total=request.POST['team_number'])
        return redirect(reverse('books', args=()))
    return render(request, 'template_name.html')
```

Comment: now its not giving this error, TypeError at /books/f/
'QueryDict' object is not callable

Comment: @Ahmed oops, it should be `request.POST['team_number']`.

Comment: now it gave multivaluedictkeyerror so I changed it to request.POST.get('team_number') but now its giving IntegrityError at /books/f/
null value in column "total" violates not-null constraint. Is the method wrong?

Comment: you are double quoting the name="team_number attribute of the input

Comment: oh it worked now, I was not returning correctly, Thankyou so much